# how to handle click only one <li> item in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First, Sorry for my Bad English. I want to make a category tree component and blew is my rendering code.

```
class tree extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showBig1: false,
        showBig2: false,
        showSmall1: false,
        showSmall2: false,
        current: 'fake',
        fake: false
    };

}

toggleBigMenu = (type, current_now) => {
    this.state = {
        [current_now]: false,
        [type]: true,
        current: type
    }
}


render() {
    const {showBig1, showBig2, showSmall1, showSmall2} = this.state
    return (
        <div>
            <li className={showBig1 ? "on" : "off"} onClick={this.toggleBigMenu("showBig1", current)}>
                <Link to="#">
                    <span>BIG MENU 1</span>
                </Link>
            </li>
            <li className={showBig2 ? "on" : "off"} onClick={this.toggleBigMenu("showBig2", current)}>
                <Link to="#">
                    <span>BIG MENU 2</span>
                </Link>
                <ul>
                    <li className={showSmall1 ? "on" : "off"} onClick={this.toggleBigMenu("showSmall1", current)}>
                        <Link to="#">
                            <span>SMALL MENU 1</span>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className={showSmall2 ? "on" : "off"} onClick={this.toggleBigMenu("showSmall2", current)}>
                        <Link to="#">
                            <span>SMALL MENU 2</span>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

and I want to click only one 'li' item at a time.
But When I click BIG MENU1, it clicked with BIG MENU 2.
And BIG MENU 2's state turn true, but I want to turn BIG MENU 1's state.

I don't know how to solve it.. please anyone help me.
Thank you.

Comment: By writing `onClick={this.toggleBigMenu("showBig1", current)}` you are invoking `this.toggleBigMenu` directly on render. You can create a new function that will be invoked when the event occurs instead: `onClick={() => this.toggleBigMenu("showBig1", current)}`. Where is `current` coming from in your render method?

Comment: @Tholle Thanks for your comment. 
I forgot to declare 'current' when moving code to the post. Sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing `onClick={this.toggleBigMenu("showBig1", current)}` you are invoking `this.toggleBigMenu` directly on render. You can create a new function that will be invoked when the event occurs instead.

Instead of passing in `current` every time you change menu, you can reset all menus to being `false` and just setting the clicked one to `true`.

Since you have menus inside other menus, it's also a good idea to call `event.stopPropagation()` on the click event so the nested menus have a chance of being selected.

**Example**

```js
const menus = {
  showBig1: false,
  showBig2: false,
  showSmall1: false,
  showSmall2: false
};

class Tree extends React.Component {
  state = { ...menus };

  toggleMenu = (event, type) => {
    event.stopPropagation();

    this.setState({
      ...menus,
      [type]: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { showBig1, showBig2, showSmall1, showSmall2, current } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <li
          style={{ backgroundColor: showBig1 ? "green" : "red" }}
          onClick={event => this.toggleMenu(event, "showBig1")}
        >
          <span>BIG MENU 1</span>
        </li>
        <li
          style={{ backgroundColor: showBig2 ? "green" : "red" }}
          onClick={event => this.toggleMenu(event, "showBig2")}
        >
          <span>BIG MENU 2</span>
          <ul>
            <li
              style={{ backgroundColor: showSmall1 ? "green" : "red" }}
              onClick={event => this.toggleMenu(event, "showSmall1")}
            >
              <span>SMALL MENU 1</span>
            </li>
            <li
              style={{ backgroundColor: showSmall2 ? "green" : "red" }}
              onClick={event => this.toggleMenu(event, "showSmall2")}
            >
              <span>SMALL MENU 2</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Tree />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Gosh Thank you so much for helping me.Can I ask you one more question? When I try this code, when the link is moved by clicking li, the highlight of the menu disappears and is initialized. Is there a way to prevent this? Thank you so much again.

Comment: @abbey You're welcome! Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Maybe you could open up a new question demonstrating your issue if you can't find a solution?

Comment: Yes It's work for me! I'm really thanks for your help.